# Can Someone Help Explain this Subquery and How it Works

Tags: sql, subquery

Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:

```
continent as Continent,
name as Name,
area as Area
FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL(
    SELECT
    area
    FROM world y
    WHERE y.continent = x.continent
    AND area > 0
)
```

I don't get why you have to do y.continent = x.continent in this case. Can someone explain what is happening here? Beginner to SQL thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)  and returns all of the records where the `continent` matches the `continent` for that particular record in the "outer" query.

> I don't get why you have to do y.continent = x.continent in this case.

If you didn't, it would return *all* records from `world` and not just the ones where the `continent` matches.

The query looks to roughly translate to:

> Give me all of the countries whose area is greater than or equal to all of the other countries on the same continent

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Reading it clarfies it a bit for me. What would be the order of operations in this particular query?

Comment: Nor sure what you mean by order of operations.  SQL is a set-based language and not procedural, so there's not a defined "order of operations" in all cases.  The compiler can rearrange things in many different ways to optimize the performance.